# How to load CKEditor only on the page that needs it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, turbolinks

I'm using [CKEditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#usage) gem. It is only used on admin pages. I want to only use it on the pages that require it. I commented out the Sprocket directive in `application.js`

```
// only load on required pages // require ckeditor/init
```

And I add it to the form page at the top

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/init' %>
```

However it only works sometimes. If I reload a page *without* it, and navigate to a page *with* it, then it loads the script, but fails to decorate the text box. There are no console errors.

If I reload a page *with* it, then it succeeds and decorates the text box.

If I reload a page *without* it, navigate to a page *with* it, navigate to a page *without* it, then navigate back to a page *with* it, then it succeeds and decorates the text box, but gives the console warning

> [CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-destroy-iframe.
>   [CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-editor-destroy-iframe

That link says

> Description: The editor’s  could not be destroyed correctly because it had been unloaded before the editor was destroyed. Make sure to destroy the editor before detaching it from the DOM.

I'm pretty sure this is a Turbolinks problem. I would add a `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load'` event handler, but I don't know what DOM id to use or how to 'initialize' or 'destroy' CKEditor.

Rails 5.2.2

---

I tried this, fixing the class and event name https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#turbolink-integration

```
ready = ->
  $('.ckeditor_class').each ->
    CKEDITOR.replace $(this).attr('id')
    console.log("ck'd "+$(this).attr('id'))

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

But it gave a console error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

---

I tried this

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  setTimeout ->
    if CKEDITOR?
      $('.ckeditor_class').each ->
        CKEDITOR.replace $(this).attr('id')
  , 1000
```

And it works when navigating from a page that *doesn't* have it to a page that *does* have it, but when reloading a page that *does* have it, it gives the console error

> Uncaught The editor instance "question_prompt" is already attached to the provided element.

There is no way to know if it has been initialized or not. Ex: `CKEDITOR.instances` doesn't have a `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
check_ckeditor_loaded = function($el) {
  if (typeof CKEDITOR !== "undefined" && CKEDITOR !== null) {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(CKEDITOR.instances)) {
      CKEDITOR.replace($el.attr('id'));
    }
    # make other magic 
  } else {
    setTimeout((function() {
      return check_ckeditor_loaded($el);
    }), 100);
  }
};


$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.ckeditor_class').each ->
    $el = $(this)
    check_ckeditor_loaded($el);
```